# Setting jCheckBox invisible in jTable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a `jTable` with two columns.First column is set as Boolean(for checkbox) and second column has String value.As I am using `Netbeans`,checkbox got added into all rows of first column. I tried to add it only for those rows which have value in the second column. I used the code for trying that,

```
private class CustomCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer#getTableCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTable, java.lang.Object, boolean, boolean, int, int)
   */

        @Override
  public Component  getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,boolean        isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

    Component rendererComp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus,row, column);

             for(int i=row;i<jTable1.getRowCount();i++){

                if(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 1)==null){
                   jTable1.setValueAt(true, i, 0);
                    //checkbox.setOpaque(false);


                }
            }

        return this ;
  }

 }
```

If I try to set value 'true' for all other checkbox in the above for loop it's working well. How can I set it invisible for rest of  the rows.

**EDIT:**

I am adding my code in this

```
   package e2;

    import java.awt.Component;
    import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
    public class JTable_CheckBox extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        /** Creates new form JTable_CheckBox */

        JCheckBox checkbox=new JCheckBox();

        public JTable_CheckBox() {
            initComponents();
               jTable1.setValueAt("John",0,1);
               jTable1.setValueAt("James",1,1);
               jTable1.setValueAt("Janet",2,1);
               jTable1.setValueAt("Tom",3,1);

    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new CheckboxCellRenderer());
        }


     public static void main(String args[]) {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new JTable_CheckBox().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        public class CheckboxCellRenderer extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer {

        public CheckboxCellRenderer() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                //here i am trying to set check box invisible,but here i am setting as selected

           for(int i=row;i<table.getRowCount();i++){

                    if(table.getValueAt(i, 1)==null){
                       table.setValueAt(true, i, 0);
                        //checkbox.setOpaque(false);

                    }
                }
            return this;
            }

        }
     // Variables declaration - do not modify
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
        private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
        // End of variables declaration

    }
```

Comment: try  checkbox.setVisible(false);

Comment: I tried that also...nothing happens..:(

Comment: unrelated: _never-ever_ change any state of the table in the renderer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TableCellRenderer are used in tables to paint the various cells of the table reusing the same component. The table automatically sets up the proper context, component bounds and invokes the `getTableCellRendererComponent` for each cell of the table that needs to be painted (the first time the table is displayed all visible cells are painted and then after, upon TableModel notification, the appropriate cells are repainted).

So in your TableCellRenderer you certainly do not need to iterate over the cells of the table trying to set values. This just does not make sense. Remember you are implementing the interface `TableCellRender` which has a contract you need to respect.

From the Javadoc:

> Returns the component used for drawing the cell. This method is used
>   to configure the renderer appropriately before drawing.

So all you need to do is return a component representing the `value` parameter properly. Possibly, you can modify the component to indicate that the cell has the focus or not, and wheter it is currently selected or not. Nothing more, nothing less.

Now, coming to your question: if you want to display a checkbox only for rows that have a value implement a TableCellRenderer returning a checkbox and modify its visibility according to the value in column 1 (second column).

This example is working:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TestTable {

    public class CheckboxCellRenderer extends JPanel implements TableCellRenderer {

        private JCheckBox checkBox;

        public CheckboxCellRenderer() {
            super(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
            setOpaque(false);
            checkBox = new JCheckBox();
            checkBox.setOpaque(false);
            checkBox.setHorizontalAlignment(JCheckBox.CENTER);
            add(checkBox);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            Object valueInColumn1 = table.getValueAt(row, 1);
            checkBox.setVisible(valueInColumn1 != null);
            checkBox.setSelected(value instanceof Boolean && (Boolean) value);
            return this;
        }
    }

    private JFrame f;
    private JTable table;

    private class MyObject {
        private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

        private String value;

        private boolean selected;

        public MyObject(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public PropertyChangeSupport getPropertyChangeSupport() {
            return propertyChangeSupport;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
            propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("value", null, value);
        }

        public boolean isSelected() {
            return selected;
        }

        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            if (this.selected != selected) {
                this.selected = selected;
                propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("selected", !selected, selected);
            }
        }

    }

    protected void initUI() {
        List<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<TestTable.MyObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            MyObject object = new MyObject(i % 3 == 1 ? null : "Row " + (i + 1));
            objects.add(object);
        }
        table = new JTable(new MyTableModel(objects));
        table.setRowHeight(20);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new CheckboxCellRenderer());
        f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

    public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements PropertyChangeListener {

        private List<MyObject> objects;

        public MyTableModel(List<MyObject> objects) {
            super();
            this.objects = objects;
            for (MyObject object : objects) {
                object.getPropertyChangeSupport().addPropertyChangeListener(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getSource() instanceof MyObject) {
                int index = objects.indexOf(evt.getSource());
                fireTableRowsUpdated(index, index);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return objects.size();
        }

        public MyObject getValueAt(int row) {
            return objects.get(row);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return getValueAt(rowIndex).isSelected();
            case 1:
                return getValueAt(rowIndex).getValue();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 0) {
                getValueAt(rowIndex).setSelected(Boolean.TRUE.equals(value));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return columnIndex == 0 && getValueAt(rowIndex).getValue() != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return Boolean.class;
            case 1:
                return String.class;
            }
            return Object.class;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return "Selected";
            case 1:
                return "Value";
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTable().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

PS: I did not take isSelected/hasFocus into account, if you want we can come to that later.

Comment: Thank you...now i got some idea..can you please tell me the meaning of this line..."setSelected(value instanceof Boolean && (Boolean)value);"

Comment: Can we do in this way,(literally),check the row value of column1,if it's null take component value of column 0 and make setVisible false..Am i right?

Comment: @Tickua The renderer returns a checkbox, so `setSelected(value instanceof Boolean && (Boolean)value);` will simply make the checkbox selected if the `value` is a Boolean and its value is equals to `true`.

Comment: @Tickua For the second comment: I think you don't quite understand the concept of rendering. There is no component inside a JTable! So you cannot change the visibility of a cell using table.getComponentInCell(0,0).setVisible(false). Instead what you do is, inside the TableCellRenderer, you choose to show something or not based on the information provided by the parameters of `getTableCellRendererComponent`. Take a look at the code I provided: I check the value in column 1 and if it is null I make the checkbox invisible (and therefore it won't be painted), if it is not null I make it visible.

Comment: -1 for returning null! There is nothing in the contract of renderer which allows that.

Comment: @kleopatra You are right, I completely overlooked that aspect. I was actually going through the code with the debugger and saw that JTable was handling the case were `null` was returned so I thought it was acceptable (although I found it weird). But you are correct, nothing in the interface says that I can return null. ;-) I edited the post with a more correct answer.

Comment: tend to give out another virtual -1 for the overcomplicated model (in the context of this question), refraining because I'm not entirely sure I understand the OP ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra the OP asked for the checkbox to appear only if a the value in column 1 is not null. Displaying a checkbox means that the value should be editable as well, so I need to create a very small "Business" model where I can get some kind of value and have some kind of selected state. I don't see how an object containing 2 properties is overcomplicated. The rest of the code is just wiring everything together.

Comment: how did I know you would jump onto it <g> My preference is to not add concepts unrelated to the original question, at least not for obvious beginners. The only model-related thingy the OP needs to understand is to update the value of the boolean column when updating the value in the other, no business object involved. That's arguable, of course, should have marked my comment more clearly as my opinion :-)

Comment: @kleopatra:I agree with your comment. I dont have a correct idea about the concept of rendering and editing.And I am trying my best to study on it.But  I am not getting a start which is clear to me. When I ask a question about a topic all are giving a detailed copy paste code from somewhere. So nothing else happens,I am just getting  more confused..

Comment: @Tickua The example I provided aims at giving a fully-working example that you can run and see how it behaves and should hopefully help you get started. After a few months on SO, I tend to provide full-code instead of providing some snippets because I get all the time "This is not working", "I can't make it work", etc... The code is not copy-pasted, it has been fully written by me for this question. If you want something less verbose, I would advise you to post your own code. We could then modify it to show how to achieve your goals.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: Sorry..I was that much confused that's why.I have added my code in the question,as it's in Netbeans, i didnt add the system generated code for jTable.Please check it..

Comment: @Tickua No prob ;-) Simply replace your CheckboxCellRenderer with mine (copy-paste the first inner class of the example) or the one of kleopatra and it should work as such

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: I took the first inner class of your code[CheckboxCellRenderer], it gave me the result which I wanted,there are only 4 checkbox visible corresponding to 4 names,but it jz acts like a like an image,when I click on it no tick mark nothing..why?:(

Comment: @Tickua that's the second part (editors). You need to set an editor on the first column. You can get started with something like this: `table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(new JCheckBox()));`. The only "problem" is that your table model is saying that all cells are "editable", so rows where the checkbox don't appear will still be editable. When you click on it you will actually see a checkbox.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13441/discussion-between-tickua-and-guillaume-polet)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: Ok..Thank You..Now it's working..Actually i set it as nonediatble in my tablemodel,when i converted it to editable,it started working..Thanks a lot for your support...:)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: If I try to group the checkbox in first column all checkboxes are getting visible.How can I group them properly?

Answer (score 4):

First, you *must* understand the renderer/editor mechanism. To achieve that, read f.i. the corresponding chapter in the online tutorial referenced in the [Swing tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).

Second, for best visual appearance, implement a custom renderer by re-using the defaults installed by the JTable itself, something like:

```
public class CompoundRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

    TableCellRenderer booleanRenderer;
    TableCellRenderer defaultRenderer;

    public CompoundRenderer(TableCellRenderer booleanRenderer, 
        TableCellRenderer defaultRenderer) {
        this.booleanRenderer = booleanRenderer;
        this.defaultRenderer = defaultRenderer;
    }
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(..., Object value, ....) {
        if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            return booleanRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(...);
        }
        return defaultRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(...);
    }
}

// usage
JTable myTable ...
TableCellRenderer compound = new CompoundRenderer(
       myTable.getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class), myTable.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class));
// either register for all booleans
myTable.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, compound);
// or register for a particular column
myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(someIndex).setCellRenderer(compound);
```

Answer (score 2):

As the saying goes: many ways lead to Rome.

I just had a similar problem, namely I have a table with a column containing checkboxes, and I want to hide the checkbox in the first row. After  evaluating the other solutions I come up with something slightly different (adapted for the original question):

Create a specific CheckBoxRenderer class:

```
public class CheckBoxRenderer extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer {

    CheckBoxRenderer() {
      setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

      Object valueInColumn1 = table.getValueAt(row, 1);
      if (valueInColumn1 == null) {
          JLabel x=new JLabel();
          return x;
      } 
      setSelected((value != null && ((Boolean) value).booleanValue()));
      return this;
    }
}
```

Step number 2: attach the renderer to te column:

```
paramTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new CheckBoxRenderer());
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I had a similar need and found sers answer quite helpful. One addition I found that I needed to include was to create a CheckBoxEditor. Otherwise, when I clicked on the cell, I saw the checkbox appear momentarily. So I added something like this:

```
public class CheckBoxEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
{
   private JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();

   CheckBoxEditor()
   {
      super( checkBox );
   }

   @Override
   public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(
                       JTable  table,
                       Object  value,
                       boolean isSelected,
                       int     row,
                       int     column )
   {
      if ( row != 1 )
      {
         return super.getTableCellEditorComponent(
                        table, value, isSelected, row, column );
      }
      else
      {
         return null;
      }
   }
}
```

Then you'd do something like:

```
paramTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellEditor( new CheckBoxEditor() );
```

Worked for me, anyway.

Another note is that if your cells have a background color, you can extend sers answer by adding the lines:

```
x.setOpaque( true );
x.setBackground( MYCOLOR );
```

Setting the JLabel to opaque is the key, as can be found in other Stack Exchange answers on similar topics.