# jcheckbox in jtable is doing nothing on clicking it, please help needfull

Tags: jtable, jcheckbox, tablemodel

My table model is as follows. The first coloumn of my table is checkbox. I am able to put checkbox in jtable but when I cliked on that checkbox it does nothing. I used the `DefaultTableCellRenderer` to put checkbox in my table.

```
public class MyTableModel implements TableModel {

    ArrayList<PersonDTO> list=new ArrayList<PersonDTO>();

    String headerName[]={"checkbox","student_id","name"};

    public MyTableModel(ArrayList<PersonDTO> list) {
        this.list=list;  
    }


    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        System.out.println(list.size());
         return list.size();

    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
       // System.out.println(headerName.length);
        return headerName.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
       // System.out.println(headerName);
        return headerName[columnIndex];


    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        switch(columnIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                return JCheckBox.class;
                //return JCheckBox.class;
            case 1:
                return Integer.class;
            case 2:
                return String.class;


        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
         return  true;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        PersonDTO personDTO=list.get(rowIndex);
         switch(columnIndex)
        {
            case 0:
               //System.out.println(personDTO.isCheckbox());
              return personDTO.getCheckBox();
                //return new JCheckBox();

            case 1:
                //System.out.println(personDTO.getName());
                return personDTO.getUserId();
            case 2:
                return personDTO.getName();


        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 

    }

    @Override
    public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

}
```

Comment: Just check this link..


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328451/setting-jcheckbox-invisible-in-jtable

Comment: You just check your jTable columns properties ,that columns are editable or not??...If field is non editable then that can changed into editable.Then you can most probably solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use Boolean class for the check box column.

```
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
switch(columnIndex)
{
    case 0:
        // return JCheckBox.class;
           return Boolean.class;
    case 1:
        return Integer.class;
    case 2:
        return String.class;
}
   return null;
}
```